# How can i detect pattern a+b+ with Flink CEP

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

Flink CEP not working for my pattern.
I have a sequence for example aabbbbaaaabbabb(a+b+).
I want the function process show output like this:
{aabbbb} {aaaabb} {abb}

```
AfterMatchSkipStrategy skipStrategy = AfterMatchSkipStrategy.skipPastLastEvent();
Pattern<JsonNode, JsonNode> attemptPattern = Pattern.<JsonNode>begin("first", skipStrategy)
        .where(new SPCondition() {
            @Override
            public boolean filter(JsonNode element, Context<JsonNode> context) throws Exception {
                return element.get("endpoint").textvalue().equals("A");
            }
        }).oneOrMore()
        .next("second")
        .where(new SPCondition() {
            @Override
            public boolean filter(JsonNode element, Context<JsonNode> context) throws Exception {
                return element.get("endpoint").textvalue().equals("B");
            }
        }).oneOrMore();
```

my result:

{aab} {aaaab} {ab}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow insist that it take all of the B's it can, and not just match after the first one. Here's one way to do that.

```
public class CEPExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(1);
        DataStream<String> events = env.fromElements("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "x");

        AfterMatchSkipStrategy skipStrategy = AfterMatchSkipStrategy.skipToFirst("end");
        Pattern<String, String> pattern = Pattern.<String>begin("first", skipStrategy)
                .where(new SimpleCondition<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(String element) throws Exception {
                        return (element.equals("a"));
                    }
                }).oneOrMore()
                .next("second")
                .where(new SimpleCondition<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(String element) throws Exception {
                        return (element.equals("b"));
                    }
                }).oneOrMore()
                .next("end")
                .where(new SimpleCondition<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(String element) throws Exception {
                        return (!element.equals("b"));
                    }
                });

        PatternStream<String> patternStream = CEP.pattern(events, pattern);
        patternStream.select(new SelectSegment()).print();
        env.execute();
    }

    public static class SelectSegment implements PatternSelectFunction<String, String> {
        public String select(Map<String, List<String>> pattern) {
            return String.join("", pattern.get("first")) + String.join("", pattern.get("second"));
        }
    }

}
```

If instead you want to match a+b*, while I feel like there should be a simpler solution, here's something that works:

```
public class CEPExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(1);
        DataStream<String> events = env.fromElements("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "x");

        AfterMatchSkipStrategy skipStrategy = AfterMatchSkipStrategy.skipToFirst("end");
        Pattern<String, String> pattern = Pattern.<String>begin("a-or-b", skipStrategy)
                .where(new SimpleCondition<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(String element) throws Exception {
                        return element.equals("a") || element.equals("b");
                    }
                }).oneOrMore()
                .next("end")
                .where(new IterativeCondition<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(String element, Context<String> ctx) throws Exception {
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        ctx.getEventsForPattern("a-or-b").iterator().forEachRemaining(list::add);
                        int length = list.size();
                        if (!element.equals("a") && !element.equals("b")) return true;
                        return (((length >= 1) && element.equals("a") && list.get(length - 1).equals("b")));
                    }
                });

        PatternStream<String> patternStream = CEP.pattern(events, pattern);
        patternStream.select(new SelectSegment()).print();
        env.execute();
    }

    public static class SelectSegment implements PatternSelectFunction<String, String> {
        public String select(Map<String, List<String>> pattern) {
            return String.join("", pattern.get("a-or-b"));
        }
    }

}
```

For what it's worth, I generally find [match_recognize](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/match_recognize.html) offers a more straightforward DSL for pattern matching with Flink.

Comment: Dear David. thanks for your response. solved my problem but also I want a+ b* pattern. how can I detect a+ b*?(for example input:aaaaaaa pattern detected:aaaaaaa)

Comment: See my updated answer as well as my suggestion that you investigate using Flink SQL with match_recognize (which compiles into CEP underneath) instead.